# Sitecore instance restart caused by a FileSystemWatcher in PaaS

Tags: paas

My Sitecore instance deployed onto Azure Web App Service has issues with the `FileSystemWatcher` forcing it to restart randomly.

How can I improve the stability of my Sitecore website on Azure Web App?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sitecore PaaS best practices recommend to disable `FileSystemWatchers` to improve stability of your Sitecore website.

The below is an example of a patch config file to do so:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">    
  <sitecore> 
      <watchers> 
         <patch:delete /> 
      </watchers> 
    <mediaLibrary> 
      <watcher> 
        <ignoreList> 
          <patch:delete /> 
        </ignoreList> 
      </watcher> 
    </mediaLibrary> 
  </sitecore> 
</configuration>
```

Also, it is recommended  to disable  the `Upload Watcher` to improve security of your Sitecore instance and ensure that the only way to upload files to Sitecore is from the Media Library, i.e. you can only upload files from within the Sitecore client and have control over the files that are uploaded. Read more [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/secure-the-file-upload-functionality.html).

When you disable the `Upload Watcher`, files that are placed in the upload folder are not automatically uploaded to the Media Library.

To disable the `Upload Watcher`:
Open your `web.config` file and remove the following string from the `<system.webServer><modules>` section:

```
<add type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher,Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreUploadWatcher"/>
```